# Changing only 1 element of class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stack, positioning

I'm not quite sure if this is actually possible in JQuery but it should be basically I need to make a stack of pages on website like shown on the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlqHk.png) but I'd rather do it using JQuery instead of making the ID css for each of them. While reading other questions related to the topic I've encountered these things `$( this ).children( 'li.target' ).css("border", "3px double red");`
and `$( this ).find( 'li.target' ).css("border", "3px double red");` (yeah I changed li to div), console doesn't show that there is an error with the code but it doesn't work regardless. The thing I need is an array of elements of class named "pages" and code sample how to relate to a single object of this class in JQuery, also I'm familiar with JS syntax if this can be done in it.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you showed HTML sample, people could help you

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You definitely don't need jQuery to accomplish this - it can be done just as easily in ordinary JS.

Comment: Sample of style which will be changed to a single class `#div1
  {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 top: 6%;
 height: 842px;
 width: 595px;
 background: black;
 border: 2px solid red;
 z-index: 100;
  }` top,left,z-index will be determined by the index of element in class HTML sample is just plain <div id=""> </div> going to change id for class as written in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eq` function in `jQuery` to get an item at a specific index after selecting a list of items

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$( "li" ).eq( 5 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed also do you happen to know how to make a array of the elements in class? cause I'd like the positioning to work in a for loop so it would position all of them at once and i need the index for that. Also a function that returns the amount of elements in that class would work for this purpose

Comment: @B0re To loop through items you can just use `.each`: https://api.jquery.com/each/ which also has the index if needed. To get the number of elements you just use `.length`

Comment: sure thing will check it right away and mark in 8h time